# $X$ is separable for $X_n=\{0,1\}$

Tags: general-topology

For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, let $X_n=\{0,1\}$ and $X=\Pi_{n\in \mathbb{N}}X_n$.

How do I prove that $X$ is separable?

I am trying to find a countable dense set in $X$. I let $x\in X$ $x=\{x_1,x_2,...\}$, and $x_i=0$ or $1 \forall \,i$.

Can I construct a function $f:X \to \{0,1\}$?

Comment: There is a result from [Pondiczery, Hewitt and Marczewski][1], which you maybe interested in:
>**If there are not more than $\mathfrak{c}$ ( which is the continuum), separable topological spaces, then their product is still separable.**


  [1]: http://planetmath.org/HewittMarczewskiPondiczeryTheorem.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that the set of sequences which are eventually zero is countable and dense.

Comment: Which sequences are you talking about? Is it the one I have?

Comment: The elements of $X$ are binary sequences. It is wise to understand what is the space before trying to analyze its properties. Things like "what are the elements of the space" and "what is the topology of the space?" and "how does a basic open set look like?" should be questions asked before writing this sort of question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just don't understand. I know that $[0,1]^\mathbb{N}$ is separable in the product topology, but I don't know how to work with this